# Starting a few days ago, I have multiple unwanted app launches on startup. Help!

Tags: login-items

Starting a few days ago, several apps have begun to launch on startup, without my having set them to do so.

None of them show up in "Login Items." None of them show "Open at login" in the dock right-click menu. I have never had this system set to reopen anything that was open at power-down, and all of these apps had been explicitly closed at power-down.

Shortly before this started, the system hung at power-down. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: When did you last run a virus check?

Comment: The apps that launch when you start up your Mac, are they apps you regularly use or rather "unusual" apps? You could try "reseting" which apps open at startup by closing all apps and then selecting "Reopen windows when logging back in" before shutting down your Mac.

Comment: Do these apps have Preferences for starting at login?  There are other ways to get launched than just being in Login Items.

Comment: @SolarMike what do you mean by virus check? MacOS, to my knowledge, doesnt come with such a utility. Can you reccomend a way to check for viruses? Which software to use?

Comment: are those web based app

Comment: @anonymous like many programs used on MacOS, there are virus checking programs written by third parties. Surprisingly even the Mac App store has some : https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1068435535?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4omaBhDqARIsADXULuX065cK_SseN4hSppgtWa536vt6yh4ZIDGMll8JHL-tauPOv8-mhLkaAsk9EALw_wcB

Comment: Something I neglected to mention in the original question: when I opened "Login Items," I found something I didn't recognize, with a name that was something to the effect of "Zoom Loader," that had an exclamation-point-in-triangle icon next to it. I removed it.

And the problem didn't happen this morning. Whether it was my deleting the login item or just the fact that I did *anything* in Login Items, or something else, I don't know.

Comment: Oh, and when I saw the first comment from "Solar Mike," I immediately ran a scan with Malwarebytes 4.16.7; it found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did , as noted in my October 10 16:42 comment notice and remove an unfamiliar "Login Item": the name was something to the effect of "Zoom Loader," and it had an exclamation-point-in-triangle icon next to it. The problem went away, and I have no idea whether it was from removing the item or from simply opening "Login Items."

Any further insights on what happened would be greatly appreciated.